# Tag removal [Help]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-removal-request

The [help](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag seems to fall into that [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) category.  I would think that 99% of the question on the site are looking for some help :)

Thoughts?

Comment: Ick. The 'advice' tag seems to go hand in hand with it, and there's some where one or the other is the only tag. Definitely need to zap both once everything has at least _one_ valid tag on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [help](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) and [advice](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) tags have been ...

***Burninated!***

[image: stupidest game I ever played]

Answer (score 3):

I searched for the [help](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag and made sure there were not going to be any untagged when help is squelched.  Should be safe to burninate!

Comment: Ditto for [tag:advice].  There was only one single out there.

Comment: Nice work Josh! Thanks for taking care of it.